# How to Remove Hidden Characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have following piece of code, which reads text files from a director. I have used a list of stopwords and after removing stopwords from the files when the words of these files along with their positions then there come extra blank characters in place of where stopword exist in the document.

For example, a file which reads like,

> Department of Computer Science // A document

after removing stop word 'of' from the document when I loop through the document then following output comes out:

> Department(0) (1) Computer(2) Science(3) //output

But blank space should not be there.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$directory = "archive/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $texts = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $contents);
    $texts = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\n ]/', '', $texts);
    $text = explode(" ", $texts);
    $text = array_map('strtolower', $text);
    $stopwords = array("a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", "for", "from", "has", "he", "in", "it","i","is", "its", "of", "on", "that", "the", "to","was", "were", "will", "with", "or", " ");
    $text = (array_diff($text,$stopwords));
    echo "<br><br>";
    $total_count = count($text);
    $b = -1;
   foreach ($text as $a=>$v)
   {
     $b++;
     echo $text[$b]. "(" .$b. ")" ." ";
   } 
 } 
}
closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Comment: Between word 'Department' and word 'Computer'. Loop indicates hidden character by placing its position i.e (1)

Comment: In my code, I have found that after removing stop-words NULL character are placed thereinto. So give me the solution to removes those. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genuinely not 100% sure about the final output of the string position, but assuming you are placing that there for reference only. This test code using regex with [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) seems to work well.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Set test content array.
$contents_array = array();
$contents_array[] = "Department of Computer Science // A document";
$contents_array[] = "Department of Economics // A document";

// Set the stopwords.
$stopwords = array("a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", "for", "from", "has", "he", "in", "it","i","is", "its", "of", "on", "that", "the", "to","was", "were", "will", "with", "or");

// Set a regex based on the stopwords.
$regex = '/(' . implode('\b|', $stopwords) . '\b)/i';

foreach ($contents_array as $contents) {

  // Remove the stopwords.
  $contents = preg_replace($regex, '', $contents);

  // Clear out the extra whitespace; anything 2 spaces or more in a row.
  $contents = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $contents);

  // Echo contents.
  echo $contents . "\n";

}
```

The output is cleaned up & formatted like this:

> Department Computer Science // document
>
> Department Economics // document

So to integrate it into your code, you should do this. Note how I moved `$stopwords` & `$regex` outside of the `while` loop since it makes no sense to reset those values on each `while` loop iteration. Set it once outside of the loop & let the stuff in the loop just be focused on what you need there in the loop:

```
<?php
$directory = "archive/";
$dir = opendir($directory);

// Set the stopwords.
$stopwords = array("a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", "for", "from", "has", "he", "in", "it","i","is", "its", "of", "on", "that", "the", "to","was", "were", "will", "with", "or");

// Set a regex based on the stopwords.
$regex = '/(' . implode('\b|', $stopwords) . '\b)/i';

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {

    // Get the contents of the filename.
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);

    // Remove the stopwords.
    $contents = preg_replace($regex, '', $contents);

    // Clear out the extra whitespace; anything 2 spaces or more in a row.
    $contents = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $contents);

    // Echo contents.
    echo $contents;

 } 
}
closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Comment: This code also deleted the sub-strings i.e in Economics, it removed 'on' and 'i' stop words and placed it as 'Ecomcs'

Comment: It is fine in the sense that it ignore sub-strings but it deletes sub-strings from the boundary e.g for word `European`, it deletes `an` from the end of word `European` and makes it `Europe`. Help me how to fix it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\b` after the `pipe |` operator as mentioned in the [answer by Giacomo1968](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24348688/117259).

```
$regex = '/(' . implode('\b|\b', $stopwords) . '\b)/i';
```

It will work.